# How to handle dynamically loaded managed libraries in c#

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, dll-injection

I wrote an application in C# and added a kind of API for it.
With this API you can write plugins as dll´s which underlie some interface rules.

I want to make it possible to open the dll file via OpenFileDialog and use its content.
My API is a managed library, so I just add a  reference, but I want to use the dll without knowing the name of the dll file. Also the namespace is another each library.

How do I load a dll and run the code within it?

Comment: Are the plugin dlls written in a .net language (like C#)? If so, they would be managed libraries.

Comment: Yes they are .NET libraries but they are implemented during the runtime

Comment: By "implemented during the runtime" so you mean you want to load them and run the methods within after the user has selected the dll file?

Comment: Erm, so what does "NON-Managed" mean in the question title?

Comment: See here for an example of loading plugin dlls: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4691/Plugin-Architecture-using-C

Comment: NON-Managed means, i don´t have access to the source code and i cannot manage it from visual studio, it´s a completely closed dll to me

@George: Yes that´s what i want to to, is there any option to do this?

Comment: The question is confusing for us as non-managed dll means a dll that isn't created using the .net managed runtime, which isn't your definition. I've edited the title to better reflect the problem.

Comment: ok, thanks, that´s making me dizzy because everyone says something divert about the meaning of managed or nonmanaged -.-

Comment: @George: the link you shared is nearly what i wanted, when you post the link agein as an answer i can accept it and close the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is commonly termed a Plugin System. Googling for something like "Create Plugin system using C#" will probably give you lots of information such as the below:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4691/Plugin-Architecture-using-C

The basic idea is:

- Define an interface that your program implements to allow a plugin to get information from your program.
- Define an interface that all plugins will implement, to allow your program to call the plugin's methods that will do something.
- Put those interfaces in a separate dll that's referenced by your program and by any plugin dlls.
- Provide some way of finding dlls with types implementing your plugin interface, e.g. your OpenFileDialog.
- Load the dll and find types that implement your plugin interface (using reflection).
- Instanciate those types using reflection.
- Call the methods on those types via the interface, as appropriate.

---

Regarding managed/non-managed. A managed DLL is one that is built/coded using the .net managed runtime. This would be things coded in a .net language such as [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

A non-managed dll is more or less anything coded in a different language.

What you referred to as a non-managed dll I would refer to as a dynamically loaded managed dll. I.e. it's still a managed dll (coded in a .net language), but isn't loaded until the program is already running.

Comment: "Googling for...'Create Plugin system using C#'..." - that´s what I´ve searched for but I couldn´t formulate it like you did :) - And another Thanks because this provides me even more functions as I basically needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can load a managed assembly from a dll file with [Assembly.LoadFrom Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) (See also [Best Practices for Assembly Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx)).